# Css div float on the flex backgroud image

Tags: css, flexbox, background-image

I want the div class item2 float on the backgroud image,
but it fails. How can I solve this?

https://codepen.io/robinnpca/pen/QXKrON

html

```
<div class="flex_img" >
      <div class="item2 ">
        <div >up1</div>
        <div >up2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item2 ">
        <div >down1</div>
        <div >down2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.item2{
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background-color: #f08bc3;
   display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex_img {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background-color: #f08bc3;
  width:100%;
  height:175px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-content:space-between;
  background-image:  url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11991/startransparent.gif"),
                  url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png");
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: center;
  background-position:left; 
}
```

below is I want
[image]

Comment: Can you explain more? Not totally understanding the question.

Comment: how should the divs arrange vertically? use `align-content: space-around` for example?

Comment: @jons I draw the image I want as above

Comment: @kukkuz it is not my purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the new code I added:

```
/* New Code */

.flex_img {
  position: relative;
}

.item2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.item2:nth-of-type(1){
  top: 0;
}

.item2:nth-of-type(2){
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Basically, I gave the image a position of relative and the two overlaid divs a position of absolute, then positioned them correctly. I also gave them a .7 opacity so you can see that they're over the image:

```css
.item2{
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background-color: #f08bc3;
   display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex_img {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background-color: #f08bc3;
  width:100%;
  height:175px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-content:space-between;
  background-image:  url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11991/startransparent.gif"),
                  url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png");
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: center; 
  background-position:left; 
}

/* New Code */

.flex_img {
  position: relative;
}

.item2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.item2:nth-of-type(1){
  top: 0;
}

.item2:nth-of-type(2){
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
   <div class="flex_img" >
      <div class="item2 ">
        <div >up1</div>
        <div >up2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item2 ">
        <div >down1</div>
        <div >down2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay. I found just need the opacity: 0.7;

Answer (score 0):

This worked for if you want to place item2 next below to each other

```
.item2{
  background-color: #f08bc3;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex_img {
  background-color: #f08bc3;
  width:100%;
  height:175px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-content:space-between;
  background-image:  url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11991/startransparent.gif"),
                  url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png");
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: center;
  background-position:left; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class name to the divs inside .item2. Then apply a background to that new class. Then you can adjust the margin and padding on the new class as well.

```
<div class="flex_img" >
  <div class="item2 ">
    <div class="newclass">up1</div>
    <div class="newclass">up2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2 ">
    <div class="newclass">down1</div>
    <div class="newclass">down2</div>
  </div>
</div>

.newclass {
  background-color: #f08bc3;
  margin: <value>;
  padding: <value>;
}
```